# Android download manager opens install page automatically without my request

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

In my application(which is run on a couple of type of tv-boxes from same manufacturer and all deviecs are rooted) I do check last version of my application from a server of my own and if there is a new version available, I download the APK file and try to install it using `pm install` command.
Though I've never started any activity to install the APK, it automatically opens the activity from intent `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`.
I've never used `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` in my whole project, so I assume that the android `DownloadManager` opens this activity automatically, and I want to stop it from doing so. Any idea how?

Here is my code:

```
//this is the method where I download the apk
//I'm putting only the important parts to make the question as short as possible
private void downloadApk() {
        if (status == State.DOWNLOADING)
            return;
        setStatus(State.DOWNLOADING);
        String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        String fileName = appType + versionInfo.getVersionName() + ".apk";
        destination += fileName;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

        String url = versionInfo.getUrl();

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDescription("Downloading new Hub version");
        request.setTitle("Downloading");

        request.setDestinationUri(uri);
        downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
        monitorDownloadPercentage();


        mContext.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
```

This method only calculates how much of the file is downloaded in percentage and calls the callback with the value. This calculated value, on it's path updates one ProgressBar and gets set as the text of a TextView.

```
private void monitorDownloadPercentage() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                downloading = true;
                while (downloading) {
                    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    q.setFilterById(downloadId);
                    Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                    int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.
                            getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                    if (upgradeStateListener != null) {
                        upgradeStateListener.onDownloading((float) bytes_downloaded / bytes_total * 100);
                    }
                    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        downloading = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

This is the broadcast receiver which gets fired when download is completed. And I'm sure this broadcast doesn't cause my problem since the only place in the code where could cause it is the `onDownloadCompleted()` method(which installs the APK using root privileges and I've commented all of it's body and it still pops up the activity.

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            final Cursor cursor = manager.query( new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Uri uri ;
                final String downloadedTo = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                uri = Uri.parse(downloadedTo);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: it's ok " + uri.getPath());
                upgradeStateListener.onDownloadCompleted(uri.getPath());
            }
            setStatus(State.DOWNLOADED);

            mContext.unregisterReceiver(this);

        }
    };
```